# Data type equivalents: MS Access Tables ↔ 'CREATE TABLE' Queries ↔ ODBC SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, types, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

What is the correct syntax when creating a table in Access with SQL?  I have tried DECIMAL, DOUBLE, NUMBER, INT... nothing lets me create an integer category with limiters.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE NONGAME (
  ITEM_NUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPTION CHAR(30),
  ON_HAND NUMBER(4),   <------- DOES NOT WORK!
  CATEGORY CHAR(3),
  PRICE DECIMAL(6,2),  <------- DOES NOT WORK!
  ANYTHING DOUBLE(4,2) <------- DOES NOT WORK!
);
```

Comment: According to documentation I just can't do this. Thanks for your incredibly useful comment!

Comment: You're welcome.  Looks like it lead you to a solution.  Below is some more information I copied from the documentation showing the differences between the 3 sets of data types in Access.

Comment: It looks like you were trying to use MySQL syntax in Microsoft Access (similar to a Microsoft SQL-Server environment.)

Answer (score 3):

## MICROSOFT ACCESS DATA TYPES

The following table shows the **Microsoft Access** data types, data types used to **create tables**, and **ODBC SQL** data types.  Some types have limitations, outlined following the table.

```sql
Microsoft Access data type        Data type (CREATE TABLE) ODBC SQL data type  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
BIGBINARY[1]                      LONGBINARY               SQL_LONGVARBINARY   
BINARY                            BINARY                   SQL_BINARY          
BIT                               BIT                      SQL_BIT             
COUNTER                           COUNTER                  SQL_INTEGER         
CURRENCY                          CURRENCY                 SQL_NUMERIC         
DATE/TIME                         DATETIME                 SQL_TIMESTAMP       
GUID                              GUID                     SQL_GUID            
LONG BINARY                       LONGBINARY               SQL_LONGVARBINARY   
LONG TEXT                         LONGTEXT                 SQL_LONGVARCHAR[2]  
MEMO                              LONGTEXT                 SQL_LONGVARCHAR[2]  
NUMBER (FieldSize= SINGLE)        SINGLE                   SQL_REAL            
NUMBER (FieldSize= DOUBLE)        DOUBLE                   SQL_DOUBLE          
NUMBER (FieldSize= BYTE)          UNSIGNED BYTE            SQL_TINYINT         
NUMBER (FieldSize= INTEGER)       SHORT                    SQL_SMALLINT        
NUMBER (FieldSize= LONG INTEGER)  LONG                     SQL_INTEGER         
NUMERIC                           NUMERIC                  SQL_NUMERIC         
OLE                               LONGBINARY               SQL_LONGVARBINARY   
TEXT                              VARCHAR                  SQL_VARCHAR[1]      
ARBINARY                          VARBINARY                SQL_VARBINARY       

[1] Access 4.0 applications only. Max 4000 B. Behaviour similar to LONGBINARY.
[2] ANSI applications only.
[3] Unicode and Access 4.0 applications only.
```

> **Note:** `SQLGetTypeInfo` returns `ODBC` data types. It will not return all *Microsoft Access* data types if more than one *Microsoft Access* type is mapped to the same `ODBC` `SQL` data type. All conversions in [**Appendix D** of the **ODBC Programmer's Reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-d-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) are supported for the `SQL` data types listed in the previous table.

---

### Limitations on Microsoft Access data types

- **`BINARY**`, **`VARBINARY**`, and **`VARCHAR`**: Creating a `BINARY`, `VARBINARY`, or `VARCHAR` column of zero or unspecified length actually returns a 510-byte column.
- **`BYTE`**: Even though a Microsoft Access `NUMBER` field with a `FieldSize` equal to `BYTE` is unsigned, a negative number can be inserted into the field when using the Microsoft Access driver.
- **`CHAR**`, **`LONGVARCHAR**`, and **`VARCHAR`**: A character string literal can contain any ANSI character (1-255 decimal). Use two consecutive single quotation marks (`''`) to represent one single quotation mark (`'`). Procedures should be used to pass character data when using any special character in a character data type column.
- **`DATE`**: Date values must be either delimited according to the ODBC canonical date format or delimited by the datetime delimiter (`#`).   Otherwise, Microsoft Access will treat the value as an arithmetic expression and will not raise a warning or error.

  - For example, the date "***`March 5, 1996`***" must be represented as `{d '1996-03-05'}` or `#03/05/1996#`; otherwise, if only `03/05/1993` is submitted, Microsoft Access will evaluate this as `3 ÷ 5 ÷ 1996`. This value rounds up to the integer `0`, and since the zero day maps to `1899-12-31`, this is the date used.
  - A pipe character (`|`) cannot be used in a date value, even if enclosed in back quotes.
- **`GUID`**: Data type limited to Microsoft Access 4.0.
- **`NUMERIC`**: Data type limited to Microsoft Access 4.0.

<sup>(More information at the [**Source**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-2017))</sup>

---

### Limitations on ODBC Desktop Driver data types

The Microsoft ODBC Desktop Database Drivers impose the following limitations on data types:

- ***All data types***     Type conversion failures might result in the affected column being set to `NULL`.
- **`BINARY`**     Creating a zero-length `BINARY` column actually returns a 255-byte `BINARY` column.
- **`DATE`**   The `DATE` data type cannot be converted to another data type (or itself) by the `CONVERT` function.
- **`DECIMAL`** (Exact Numeric)**  Not supported.
- ***`Floating-Point Data Types`***    The number of decimal places in a floating-point number may be limited by the number format set in the *International* section of the *Windows Control Panel*.
- **`NUMERIC`**    Supports maximum precision and a scale of 28.
- **`TIMESTAMP`**  The `TIMESTAMP` data type cannot be converted to itself by the CONVERT function.
- **`TINYINT`**: TINYINT values are always unsigned.
- ***`Zero-Length Strings`***: When a dBASE, Microsoft Excel, Paradox, or Textdriver is used, inserting a zero-length string into a column actually inserts a `NULL` instead.

<sup>([**Source**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-d-data-types?view=sql-server-2017))</sup>

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [**Create and Delete Tables and Indexes Using Access SQL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/access-vba/articles/create-and-delete-tables-and-indexes-using-access-sql)
- MSDN : [**`CREATE TABLE` Statement** (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb177893(v=office.12).aspx)
- *Microsoft Docs* : [**Microsoft Access Data Types**](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-2017)
- *Microsoft Docs* : [**Data Type Limitations**](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/odbc/microsoft/data-type-limitations?view=sql-server-2017)
- *Microsoft Docs* : **[Converting between ODBC and SQL Server data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/appendix-d-data-types?view=sql-server-2017)**
- *Microsoft Docs* : [**Limitations of SQL ODBC Desktop Drivers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/odbc/microsoft/limitations?view=sql-server-2017)
- Wikipedia : [**Open Database Connectivity** (ODBC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity)

---

Small addendum by [Erik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-von-asmuth):

You can actually use the `Decimal` data type in `CREATE TABLE` queries. However, this requires your statement to be executed either using ADO, or on a database that's been set to use ANSI-92 compatible syntax.

To set your database to ANSI-92 compatible syntax:

Go to File -> Options. Open the tab *Object Designers*. Go to *Query Designer*, and under SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92), check *This Database*. Now you can just execute the query. Note that this affects all queries in the database, and affects queries in various ways.

To execute a query using ADO:

In the VBA Immediate Window, execute the following line:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE TABLE NONGAME (ITEM_NUM CHAR(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  PRICE DECIMAL(6,2));"
```

Of course, you can execute more complex queries using ADO.

Comment: You might also want to explain how to use data types like `Decimal`, which are unsupported in DAO or ODBC, in create table queries. That's a large part of how I interpreted the question

Comment: @Erik - There is a list of every possible data type as well as links to instructions on how to convert to them.  It seems to be the correct course of action would be to look at the list and find a similar type (perhaps `DOUBLE` instead of `DECIMAL`) and then, use it.  The OP attempted to use `DOUBLE` but had the syntax incorrect.  My comments shared my opinion of where he was misunderstanding, and the footnotes clarify that `DECIMAL` doesn't have an exact equivalent.  Again, links will lead to the solution.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth -  Most of this was posted after the OP found an answer anyhow.  I already basically copied three entire links of information into this answer since the OP was having trouble finding it on his own.  Are you suggesting I copy a few more?

Comment: Meh, you can use `Decimal` just fine in Access by either switching mode to SQL-92 compatible syntax or using ADO to execute the query (`CurrentProject.Connection.Execute`). I was hoping you'd add it, since I'm currently on my phone. But I'll write my own answer if you're not familiar with it or don't want to add it.

Comment: I'd like to see each question properly answered, not for the OP but for future visitors, especially since this is a common and somewhat complex issue. I'd prefer to have all the information in a single answer, so it's easier to find for future readers. I'm not one for encouraging copying, I like to write my own answers, but if you have a good source that's licensed for sharing, go ahead.

Comment: @Erik - I've put more than enough time into this answer, however you're more than welcome to edit it (or if you're unhappy with it, you're aware of your options.)

Answer (score -2):

DECIMAL and DOUBLE cannot be used in Access.  For a "price", CURRENCY is the best bet.  For my other integer, I just used NUMBER and gave it no limiters.

Comment: Both Decimal and Double are supported in the latest versions of Access (and even back to 2007 iirc). Decimal is just not supported in DDL queries executed using the GUI, ODBC or DAO. This answer is plain incorrect. You can easily check this by creating tables with these field types in the GUI. With some tricks, you can also use them in SQL statements

Comment: While it is correct to use Currency for price and amounts, Double has certainly existed in Access "always" - since version 1.0.