# Creating a Table but getting Syntax error in field definition

Tags: sql, ms-access, create-table

```
Create Table Order_Line
(
    Order_Num Char(5),
    Item_Num Char(4),
    Num_Ordered Decimal(3,0),
    Quoted_Price Decimal(6,2),
    Primary Key (Order_Num, Item_Num)
);
```

I'm taking a database class and my assignment Is asking to create a table for Order Line. When I select run to create the table I'm getting a "syntax error" in field definition and it's highlighting `DECIMAL`. I'm writing this query in Microsoft Access. Once again I'm not even classified as a rookie on this and would greatly appreciate someone helping explain what I'm doing wrong with this. Thanks in advance Stack overflow community.

Comment: Did you try the other capitalization (`Decimal` instead of `DECIMAL`) that you used?

Comment: SQL datatypes are highly vendor-specifc. Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Yes, I tried Decimal instead of DECIMAL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data type equivalents: MS Access Tables ↔ 'CREATE TABLE' Queries ↔ ODBC SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110937/data-type-equivalents-ms-access-tables-%e2%86%94-create-table-queries-%e2%86%94-odbc-sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Currency to get you over this detail.

```
Create Table Order_Line
(
Order_Num Char(5),
Item_Num Char(4),
Num_Ordered Currency,
Quoted_Price Currency,
Primary Key (Order_Num, Item_Num)
);
```

Currency is like Decimal (15,4)

I think your original sql statement would have worked in previous versions of Access.
The Manual Query Designer will still allow you to change the decimal places per field for Number and Large Number.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is great information to know!